# API URI naming-similar functionality

Tags: api, uri

We already have an API with the URI as Post/v1/payees used for the functionality to add payees. Another API has to be designed for this functionality but in this API only the control flow id shall need to be sent instead of all the fields required for adding the payee. The required fields shall be taken from cache for this API. Please help in suggesting the name for this API.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why is "Post" even part of your API endpoint? you don't need that as part of the URI because that information is already in the payload itself as the HTTP action

Comment: No the above is including the HTTP method, ''POST'' is not part of the API endpoint